# AWK how to permanently remove a date field from each line of a datafile when date value is older than x days?

Tags: date, awk, sed

I have a todo list in [todo.txt](https://github.com/todotxt/todo.txt) format.

I'd like to find the starting time ('t:2023-05-18') for all tasks with a date older than 10 days and remove the field from each matching line.

#### Sample Input Data

```
(A) Important task +project @context t:2023-05-07 due:2023-6-01 rec:1d
(B) Paint bedroom wall +house @bedroom t:2023-05-07 due:2023-6-07 rec:1d
(C) Pick up dry cleaning due:2023-05-19 +home @town
(C) Buy kitchen towels t:2023-05-19 +house @town
```

#### Expected Output Data

```
(A) Important task +project @context due:2023-6-01 rec:1d
(B) Paint bedroom wall +house @bedroom due:2023-6-07 rec:1d
(C) Pick up dry cleaning due:2023-05-19 +home @town
(C) Buy kitchen towels t:2023-05-19 +house @town
```

I'd like to remove the `t:2023-05-07` field but **only** if the date is more than 10 days from today ('2023-05-18').

#### What I've Tried

I can set the date to 10 days ago using `tenDaysAgo=$(date -d "-10 days" +%Y-%m-%d)`  and then pass it through to [Ed Morton's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) script which checks if the date in the ('`t:`') field on each input line is in the past or not:

**start-past.awk:**

```
{
    orig = $0
    sched = ""
    for (i=NF; i>0; i--)
    {
        if ( sub(/^t:/,"",$i) )
        {
            sched = $i
        }
    }
    sched = substr(sched,1,10)
    $0 = orig
}
sched < date
```

I can then manipulate the **output** with a `sed` command to remove each `t:<date>` field older than 10 days ago but I can only affect the **output** with this method and I need to update the actual **data file**.

I used the following:

```bash
$TODO_SH ls | awk '$0 ~ /t:/' \
| awk -v date="$tenDaysAgo" -f ~/bin/todo/start-past.awk \
|sed -E 's/t:[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}//g' | sort -k2
```

#### My Results

I have managed to remove the '`t:`' field only from the **output** of viewing the todo.txt lines and I need to make these changes permanent in the datafile while only updating the relevant lines.

I presume I need some sort of `gawk loop` within the `start-past.awk` script that I'm using but this is where my `awk` abilities stop short.

Comment: AWK works better with data that are uniform. Your records (lines) have many optional fields which makes it difficult to parse. Summary: It can be done in AWK, but with lots of pain. I recommend using a different language.

Comment: you have only supplied one line of sample data; will all lines have this same exact format? will all lines have a `t:` field that needs to be removed? if you answer `no` to either of those questions then please update the question to show more sample lines (eg, different formats, `t`: fields to remove; `t:` fields to be left alone, etc)

Comment: you state that you want to *conditionally* modify the input but then only give us a single line of input ... how are we supposed to apply and/or demonstrate *conditional* modifications with a single-line sample?

Comment: how do go from `due:2023-6-01` in the sample input to `due:2023-05-01` in the expected output? please insure your data sets *match*

Comment: @makp-fuso added more data for clarity as per your request. :)

Comment: @markp-fuso: the due:2023-6-01 - due:2023-05-01 was a typo.

Comment: sample input shows two different date formats: `t:2023-05-07` and `due:2023-6-07`; will the `t:` date entries be guaranteed to *always* have a format of `YYYY-MM-DD`, or could the month or day also contain just a single digit (like the `due:` example)?  your current comparison (`sched < date`) won't necessarily work if you have to deal with single- and double-digit months and days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions:

- `t:` entries *always* contain a date of the format `YYYY-MM-DD` (ie, month and day are *always* 2 digits); otherwise we'll need to add some code to insure the month and day are expanded to 2 digits so that the string comparison (`sched < date`) works
- a line can contain zero or one `t:` entry (ie, a line will not have two, or more, `t:` entries)

To simulate the output from OP's `$TODO_SH ls` call:

```
$ cat todo.dat
(A) Important task +project @context t:2023-05-07 due:2023-6-01 rec:1d
(B) Paint bedroom wall +house @bedroom t:2023-05-07 due:2023-6-07 rec:1d
(C) Pick up dry cleaning due:2023-05-19 +home @town
(C) Buy kitchen towels t:2023-05-19 +house @town
```

One `awk` idea that replaces OP's current `awk | awk | sed` tuple:

```
$ cat todo.awk
{ if ( match($0,/t:[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/) ) {
     sched = substr($0,RSTART+2,10)
     if ( sched < date )
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
  }
}
1
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ cat todo.dat | awk -v date="$tenDaysAgo" -f todo.awk
(A) Important task +project @context due:2023-6-01 rec:1d
(B) Paint bedroom wall +house @bedroom due:2023-6-07 rec:1d
(C) Pick up dry cleaning due:2023-05-19 +home @town
(C) Buy kitchen towels t:2023-05-19 +house @town
```

**NOTES:**

- see [GNU awk : String Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) for a description of the `match()` and `substr()` functions
- not sure the purpose of OP's `sort -k2` so I'll leave it up to OP to decide if this needs to be applied
- OP mentions the need to make permanent changes to *`the datafile`* but we're not provided with any files (just the output from the `$TODO_SH ls` call); if OP has problems updating *`the datafile`* then I'd suggest asking a new question that focuses specifically on the datafile

Comment: That worked perfectly! 
I can follow most of your `awk` code except the part that actually does the substitution. Perhaps you’d be so kind to expand a little on this line:
`$0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)`

Comment: markp-fuso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7366100/markp-fuso), I read the link you mention to Gnu Awk String functions but saw nothing which explains how the update line `$0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)` in your code works. I did find this site useful on match and substr together - Print characters before and after a pattern - awk from which I can deduce that your code is doing a before and after type operation. It would still be very useful if you (or someone) can explain this line of code & how it works

Comment: @TonyBarganski that line of code is grabbing a copy of everything *before* the match, and everything *after* the match, and appending together to redefine the current line (`$0`); in other words, it's removing the `t:YYYY-MM-DD` entry *plus* the trailing space; `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` (populated by the `match()` call) are used to determine where to 'cut' the current line

Comment: @[markp-fuso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7366100/markp-fuso) An elegant solution. I'm surprised the syntax allows for multiple `substr()` statements on one line lilke that, and without any **`;`** or equivalent command separator between them. Can the `$0 = ` assignment take any number of `substr` commands separated by whitespace, or any other function commands for that matter?

Comment: `awk` doesn't require any sort of 'append' operator so just listing the items one after the other is sufficient; the only required white space is between the two `substr()` calls so as to not generate a parsing error; a nonsensical append that is 'valid' in `awk`: `some_var = substr(...) "abc" array[$3] toupper(other_var) other_var other_array[i] "end of line"` (7 items - function return values, array values, variable values, literal strings - appended together and assigned as the value to the `some_var` variable)

Comment: Miraculous little `awk` :)

Answer (score -1):

Use `awk -i inplace …`

Note, this may only work for GNU awk (gawk).

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/515441/awk-i-inplace-causes-file-to-be-empty

Comment: I understand the inline feature of `gawk` but my question is how can I get `gawk` to **conditionally** perform this based on whether the ('t:') field date is older than X days. I'm presuming I'd need some sort of `awk loop` to the `start-past.awk` script I've detailed?

Comment: Per the discussion at the link, no, the actual data file will be changed to whatever gawk would have output otherwise. (At the link, their problem was that they failed to output anything from awk and the input file thus became empty.)

Comment: Thanks, while your `awk -i inplace` was not the answer, it came in usesful for the final solutions which was: `awk -i inplace -v date="$tenDaysAgo" -f todo.awk $TODO`